# How to add two array that have the same key value pair?

Tags: php

I have two array like this

```
   $array1 = ['title' => 'title1', 'link' => 'link1'];

   $array2 = ['title' => 'title2', 'link' => 'link2']
```

the result that i would like to get is like this

```
[
  0 => [
         'title' => 'title1',
         'link' => 'link1'
       ],
  1 => [
         'title' => 'title2',
         'link'  =>  'link2'
       ]
]
```

How can I get it ? thank you

Comment: Did you actually try to do something yourself?

Comment: I want to get the result like I posted above in my question. I just need this array format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create additional array and put those arrays there:

```
 $array1 = ['title' => 'title1', 'link' => 'link1'];
 $array2 = ['title' => 'title2', 'link' => 'link2'];
 $a=array(); 
 array_push($a, $array1); 
 array_push($a, $array2);
```

OR:

```
/... 
$a[0] = $array1; 
$a[1] = $array2;
```

To print it:

```
var_dump($a); 
//or
print_r($a);
```

Comment: Yes thank you @malutki5200. It's working thank you for saving my time

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array1 = ['title' => 'title1', 'link' => 'link1'];
$array2 = ['title' => 'title2', 'link' => 'link2'];

$final_array = [];

array_push($final_array, $array1);
array_push($final_array, $array2);
var_dump($final_array);
```